How to download mycroft skills
hi i want to download this from github but i don't know how
https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-skills.git

This question is similar to: How to clone a git repository?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

So i did a bit of digging and i found this:
git clone https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-skills.git
It's that simple!
